# How to print more than one values in Pivot Table?

Tags: mysql, database, pivot

I Have a table Attendances

[image: Attendances Table]

and then I Make a Report using this Query

```
SET @sql = NULL;
    SELECT 
      GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
        CONCAT(
          'MAX(case when `tanggal` = ''',
          `tanggal`,
          ''' then `in_time`  end) AS `',
          `tanggal`, '`'
        )  ORDER BY `id_employee` ASC SEPARATOR ',\n'
      ) INTO @sql
    FROM `attendances` ;
        SET @sql2 = CONCAT('SELECT id_employee, ', @sql, ' FROM attendances GROUP BY id_employee');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql2;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Output Query :
[image: Output Query]

Question : I Want To Print in_time and out_time after clause `then` ? Is it Possible ?

Comment: Only 1 time in and timeout per day per employee?

Comment: yes sir,.. only 1time in and time out per day

Answer (score 0):

```
SET @sql = NULL;
    SELECT 
      GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
        CONCAT(
          'MAX(case when `tanggal` = ''', `tanggal`, ''' then CONCAT(in_time,''-'', out_time)  end) AS `', `tanggal`, '`'
        )  ORDER BY `id_employee` ASC SEPARATOR ',\n'
      ) INTO @sql
    FROM `attendances` ;
        SET @sql2 = CONCAT('SELECT id_employee, ', @sql, ' FROM attendances GROUP BY id_employee');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql2;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```